# Get the next item in a .each loop without ending the current item's iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I have a collection that I'm cycling through with an `.each` loop. Is there a way to get the next value without breaking the current iteration for a particular item in the collection?

```
collection = [foo, bar, quux]

collection.each do |item|
  # Print the current iteration "foo"
  p item #should return foo

  # Also print the next iteration "bar" 
  # without breaking the current each loop for "foo"
  p item.something_to_get_bar
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
collection.each_with_index do |item, i|
  next_item = collection[i+1]   # will be nil when past the end of the collection
end
```